# I must create a function that takes one argument (the current cell) and returns all adjacent cells (including diagonals). Ive included guidelines

Tags: python

```
new_board()
```

Takes no arguments
Returns a new 4x4 grid in the form of a 2d list, where each cell contains a randomly selected upper-case character.

```
 Ex:
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
 ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
 ['M', 'N', 'O', 'P']]
```

board_to_string(board)

Takes one argument that is a 2d array representing the full 4x4 board
Returns a multi-line string representing the board that can be printed to the console:

```
[A] [B] [C] [D]
[E] [F] [G] [H]
[I] [J] [K] [L]
[M] [N] [O] [P]
```

HERE IS THE WORK IVE DONE SO FAR

```
import random
import string


alphabet_string = string.ascii_uppercase
alphabet_list = list(alphabet_string)

def new_board():
    board = []
    for i in range (0,4):
        board.append([])
        for j in range (0,4):
            board[i].append(random.choice(alphabet_list))
    return board 






def board_to_string(board):
    boardstring = ''
    for i in range(0,4):
        for j in range(0,4):
            boardstring +="["
            boardstring += board[i][j]
            boardstring += "] "
        boardstring = boardstring.rstrip()
        boardstring += "\n"
    boardstring = boardstring.rstrip()
    boardstring = boardstring.rstrip()
    
    return boardstring
```

BUT NOW I AM STUCK ON THIS
adjacent_cells(current_cell)
Takes one argument
A tuple representing the coordinates of the current cell
Returns a list of tuples representing the coordinates of all adjacent cells (including above, below, left, right, and diagonals)
Should only return valid coordinates (those that exist on the board, so minimum 0 for x or y, and maximum 3 for x or y)

I hope I was able to explain this well

Comment: Being stuck is not a lot of context. What have you tried **for that particular problem**? The code you provided is not relevant to solving the question you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

```
def adjacent_cells(current_cell):
    adj_list = []
    x = current_cell[0]
    y = current_cell[1]
    if y > 0:
        adj_list.append((x, y-1))
    if y < 3:
        adj_list.append((x, y+1))
    if x > 0:
        adj_list.append((x-1, y))
    if x < 3:
        adj_list.append((x+1, y))
    if y > 0 and x > 0:
        adj_list.append((x-1, y-1))
    if y > 0 and x < 3:
        adj_list.append((x+1, y-1))
    if y < 3 and x > 0:
        adj_list.append((x-1, y+1))
    if y < 3 and x < 3:
        adj_list.append((x+1, y+1))
    return adj_list
```